# How to move specific cocoapods version from list of cocoapods versions?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, cocoapods

In my Mac i run the the command **‘gem list cocoapods’** in Terminal  then i got the following result like

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cocoapods (1.1.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.38.2)
cocoapods-clean (0.0.1)
cocoapods-core (1.1.1, 1.1.0.rc.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.39.0, 0.38.2, 0.37.2)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.1, 1.0.0)
cocoapods-downloader (1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.0.0, 0.9.3, 0.9.1, 0.9.0)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0, 0.4.2)
cocoapods-search (1.0.0, 0.1.0)
cocoapods-stats (1.0.0, 0.6.2, 0.5.3)
cocoapods-trunk (1.1.1, 1.0.0, 0.6.4, 0.6.1)
cocoapods-try (1.1.0, 1.0.0,* 0.5.1, 0.4.5)
```

I think my cocoapods contain four version(**cocoapods (1.1.1, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.38.2)**).
But when i run the `pod —version`  command  gives the result  `1.1.1` . 
I checked my iOS project `podfile.lock` contain the version like `COCOAPODS: 0.38.2`.
 I would like to change my cocoapod version **to 0.38.2 from 1.1.1**.

How can i achieve this case? Please help me.

Comment: did you run `pod install` in you project dir?

Comment: Yes i run the pod install command

Comment: You want to downgrade the cocoapods ? from 1.1.1 to 0.38.2

Comment: i want to change my pod version to 0.38.2

Comment: Any specific reason to use old version of pod ?

Comment: Reason is only because my project podfile.lock contain the version 0.38.2

Comment: You can update it to `1.1.1` by `pod install` anyway I've answered your question

Answer (score 0):

To downgrade the cocoapods you have to

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install  -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 0.38.2
```

Or you can select specific version while `pod install`, don't forget to use underscore

```
pod _0.38.2_ install
```

Comment: I run 'pod _0.38.2_ install' then i got the error like  'The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 -  (currently using 0.38.2)'